# Unable to npm i x509 on osx

Tags: macos, npm, x509, macos-high-sierra

So I don't seem to be able to install the x509 package on Mac osx.

```
my-air:temp me$ node -v
v10.0.0
my-air:temp me$ npm -v
6.3.0
my-air:temp me$ npm i x509
> x509@0.3.3 install /Users/me/workspace/temp/node_modules/x509
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o
In file included from ../src/addon.cc:5:
In file included from ../include/x509.h:7:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:194:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:88:15: error: no member named 'ForceSet' in 'v8::Object'
  return obj->ForceSet(GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
... 
4 warnings and 7 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/x509/src/addon.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:225:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.0.0/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/me/workspace/temp/node_modules/x509
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! x509@0.3.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the x509@0.3.3 install script.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Am I missing a c compiler or something?